# Java: Collection.shuffle memory usage?

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks

I am using Arraylist (Classroom is a class in my code) in which I am storing huge number of data (Lots of Classroom). I am using this Arraylist in a loop to extract a single classroom and run an algorithm over it. My code shuffles the Arraylist collection at the start of the loop selects a classroom at the 0th position in the Arraylist. I am using Collection.shuffle() function for the shuffle. My problem is my code is running out of heap space and halts during running.

The code fragment looks like this

```
ArrayList<ClassroomName> names = new ArrayList<ClassroomName>(Arrays.asList(ClassroomName.values()));
for(int x=0;x<names.size();x++){
        Collections.shuffle(names);
        ClassroomName name = names.remove(0);
        int classID = getClassID(name, location);
        if(classID != -1){
            c = new Classroom(classID);
            if(c!=null){
                //System.out.println("Call findEmptySlotsForClassroom for just checking. Not retreiving");
                /*
                 * Check the capacity of the classroom and the required capacity
                 */
                DBAnnotation.annoate("classCap", "classroom", "ClassroomCapacity", true);
                int classCap = c.getClassroomCapacity();
                if(classCap >= expectedCapacity){
                    /*
                     * Find empty timeslot for the classroom
                     */
                    times = c.findOpenSlotsForClassroom(timeSlotType);
                    /*
                     * If atleast one empty slot is found, return the classroom in which it was found
                     */
                    if(times.size()>0){
                        DBAnnotation.annoate("loc", "classroom", "ClassroomLocation", true);
                        ClassroomLocation loc = c.getClassroomLocation();

                        DBAnnotation.annoate("cName", "classroom", "ClassroomName", true);
                        ClassroomName cName = c.getClassroomName();

                        System.out.println("Found a classroom with empty time slots:"+cName.toString()+" "
                                + ""+ loc.toString());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                c = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am of the opinion that the shuffle is causing a lot of memory usage. I am not sure what is causing the memory overflow. If anyone can help, please let me know. I am willing to provide any other missing information if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to use Random Generator to chose any class room randomely

Comment: Please paste the exception's stack trace.

Comment: the more than likely occurs before or after the shuffle, as that method is just iterating over the list and swapping items , so it has a constant and negligible memory footprint

Comment: Your opinion is wrong. `Collections.shuffle()` is an in-place operation that just performs swaps (for random-access `List`s like what you have, at least).

Comment: Thank you guys. I will paste the stack trace in some time. Also will try to see if any other function call inside the for loop is causing the error. As suggested, it seems the shuffle function is not causing a memory out of space error.

Comment: Have you considered using a profiler to see what's making up the heap?

Comment: @user3580294 No I didnt consider that. I will try and figure out the problem using a profiler. Thanks.